# Who is in debt when a bank investments in commercial paper?

Tags: accounting

If a company issues commercial paper and the bookkeeper, bank A, receives a buy order from bank B, in which bank B creates credit to buy the commercial paper, does the company has a credit in bank B or does bank B owe himself and has the asset of the commercial paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is off topic in my humble opinion, but.

The Company owes Bank B and Bank B has the paper as an asset on its balance sheet.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-entry_bookkeeping_system

Comment: I wasn't sure about where to ask this question but it seemed to fit this stack.
I cleared by doubt other way, it seems that you account it in debt or assests.